# Writing buffer contents to a file

Tags: c, image-processing

If I have a buffer in memory, which contains an image in YUV format, how can I save the buffer contents to a file, i.e., what file format should I use, and can I view the file later in an image viewer?

Comment: That depends on what image viewer you want to use, I guess.  Do you have some more details?

Comment: I have GIMP, and 'Preview' on Mac OS X.

Comment: What YUV format do you have?  Is there a reason you can't just convert to RGB to save it?  Lossy or lossless?

Comment: It's UYVY; what file extension should I used to save the memory contents to a file? And yes, I can convert the image to RGB format for viewing purposes.

Comment: You can make a composite file: put into beginning of jpeg file a RGB preview, then add to it your buffer (so you will be able to preview images with image viewers & work with YUV data in your soft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in a hurry and it's proprietary, just dump it out.  It's a lot easier than linking to PNG or TIFF libraries and getting the support code right.  I don't seem to recall most image viewers supporting UYVY format.  This would be for television video, right?  I used to just use my own formats and have a Cg shader in OpenGL to display the image.

[Edit] For a very simple and portable image format, read this: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ppm/

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted to do. I am doing that using fwrite(), but what file format should I write it to?

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  If your program is the only one that needs to view the image, you are free to use any format (including your own) to write it.  That *might* be as simple as writing 4 bytes to describe the width and height, and dumping all the pixel data.

Comment: Ahan, so I can dump all pixel data to txt file, and later can read back, without information loss?

Comment: That's correct.  But I was actually talking about a binary file which will be smaller and faster to read and write.  If your data is sitting in a contiguous block of memory, you can just `fwrite` the entire block and `fread` it in later (assuming you have allocated space of course).  As for your comment about information loss, I assume you mean loss of quality.  Obviously you need to make sure you handle file I/O errors properly to make sure that operations succeeded (one great way to lose information is to ignore file errors and assume a file was written successfully).

Comment: Since you mentioned text files, you may want to consider writing PNM format, which is a very simple and reasonably well-established file format used in Linux.  There are command-line tools to convert PNM files to and from other formats, and of course view them.  PNM supports both text and binary format.  If you store a UYVY image as grayscale, you can make reasonable sense of it in an image viewer, because you can make out the intensity values and tell your brain to ignore the chroma.

Comment: I save the file as a .pnm image; opening with GIMP, gives this error "Opening '/Users/trasheed/Desktop/Shared/buffer1.pnm' failed: PNM Image plug-In could not open image". The image just has raw byte-by-byte data.

Comment: You do have to conform to the file format specification.  From memory, raw PNM (PGM in your case, I imaging) still have a text header.  You need to also scale your width by 2 because it won't understand that you have 2-byte pixel values.

Answer (score 0):

You may use some libraries like

- http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html
- http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net
- ...